# Slim Link to tag with block contents behaving oddly

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, slim-lang

When I do

```
= link_to "/venue/XYZ"
  .content
    ...
```

It works correctly and the contents are inside the link tag.

But when I do

```
= link_to venue_path("XYZ")
  .content
    ...
```

The contents appear to be lost and all I get is

```
<a href="http://localhost/home/search">
    /venue/XYZ
</a>
```

I am not sure why this is happening.. I have tried with the `do` at the end of `link_to` as well. `/home/search` is the current controller/action

Edit:

```
- s = venue_path("XYZ").to_s
= link_to s
  .content
    ...
```

Works.. am not sure whats happening anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You missed `do` word.

Correct syntax:

```
= link_to venue_path("XYZ") do
  .content
```

`do` is a required statement when the block is passed. Seems `link_to` to work in an unpredictable way if you pass a block without `do` (how could it work at all? o_O).

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Hey, Can this explain my "Edit"? I believe I tried both do and without, as I mentioned.. My guess is that slim does some meta programming and perhaps inserts the do as needed?